# How can I detect browser back button in react class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am trying to create a function when user hit browser back button it will run function deleteHeldResort that I created.

Here is my code for deleteHeldResort:

```
deleteHeldResorts(ReservedInventoryID: number | null = null, refreshHeldResorts: boolean = true) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.setState({heldResortsShowLoader: true});
        this.reservationService.deleteHeldResorts(ReservedInventoryID)
            .then(() => {
            refreshHeldResorts && this.getHeldResorts();
            resolve();
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
            this.catchHeldResortsError(error);
            reject(error);
        });
        this.setState({
            heldResortsShowLoader: false
        });
    });
}
```

Updated code base:

```
  handleNavigateBack = useCallback(
    (event) => {
             
           // call your function here with whatever argument your code provides
           this.reservationService.deleteHeldResorts(this.props.resId);

      }
    , []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('popstate', this.handleNavigateBack );
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('popstate', this.handleNavigateBack)
    }
}, [this.handleNavigateBack]);
```

Comment: How can I do that ? @Phix

Comment: Jumped the gun, wrong framework.

Comment: @Phix Yea, it's react. I think you thought it was angular

Comment: Your example seems to be a mixture of a class component and function component, which isn't valid. useCallback / useEffect can only be used in functional components, and this.props is only available in class components. Please update your example, and I might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer: class component based**

Since you're using class components, I'm adding this update.
Inside the class component having `deleteHeldResorts` function, you can listen to [popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event) event:
Remark how [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) keyword helps us keep the right `this`.

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleNavigateBack = this.handleNavigateBack.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("popstate", this.handleNavigateBack);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("popstate", this.handleNavigateBack);
  }

  handleNavigateBack(event) {
    console.log("inside callback", event);
   // change arguments as you want
    this.deleteHeldResorts(null, false);
  }

  deleteHeldResorts(ReservedInventoryID = null, refreshHeldResorts = true) {
    // your function goes down there content
    console.log("inside deleteHeldResorts");
  }

  render() {
    return <h2>popstate browser listener</h2>;
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Initial answer: function component based**

Inside the component having `deleteHeldResorts` function, you can listen to [popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event) event:

```js
// your-component.js

function YourComponent() {

   function deleteHeldResorts(ReservedInventoryID: number | null = null, 
                              refreshHeldResorts: boolean = true) {
               // your function content
      }
 
  const handleNavigateBack = useCallback(
    (event) => {
             
           // call your function here with whatever argument your code provides
           deleteHeldResorts(reservedInventoryID,refreshHeldResorts);

      }
  //  depending on your logic, add deps to this array dependency 
    }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('popstate', handleNavigateBack );
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('popstate', handleNavigateBack)
    }
  }, [handleNavigateBack])

 return ( <>something dope</>);
}
```

Comment: getting error when adding useEffect.. `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)` at `this.handleNavigateBack `.

Comment: Are you using class Components? If so, please update your question with the class shape and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes it's class component

Comment: Thanks for you patience, @NhanNguyen. I've updated my answer to add the class component version.